# How do I remove the null pointer exception from this code in processing

Tags: arduino, processing

I am trying to do this project I found in instructbles.
http://www.instructables.com/id/Touche-for-Arduino-Advanced-touch-sensing/?ALLSTEPS

There is an Arduino code and a Processing code that needs to be run to implement this project.
The codes can be found here.
https://github.com/Illutron/AdvancedTouchSensing

The arduino code runs fine. But the one in processing gives a NullPointerException error and the output is just a plain white window instead of the desired graphs.
The complete error message is as follows:

```
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
[0] "COM1"
[1] "COM12"
error, disabling serialEvent() for //./COM12
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at                
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at processing.serial.Serial.serialEvent(Serial.java:287)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.sendEvent(RXTXPort.java:732)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.eventLoop(Native Method)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$MonitorThread.run(RXTXPort.java:1575)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at processing.core.PApplet.append(PApplet.java:7966)
at sketch_130301a.serialEvent(sketch_130301a.java:751)
... 8 more
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
at processing.serial.Serial.serialEvent(Serial.java:273)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.sendEvent(RXTXPort.java:732)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.eventLoop(Native Method)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$MonitorThread.run(RXTXPort.java:1575)
```

Please help me out. I have been stuck here for a long time. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception occurs when java can't find an index in an array at that address.  Are you sure that your serial ports are valid? Have you tested serial communication using another sketch in processing?

Comment: I tested another program using serial communication and it worked fine. I can't figure out the problem.